# Index : 0 Size : 0 Error In Large Layout Screens[Android]

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, rendering, qualifiers

I have a layout that throws this error during layout previews : `Index 0 Size 0` ONLY in very large screen sizes. Also another error that I see is

`Broken rendering library , unsupported library. try using the SDK manager to get updated layout libraries`.

No such library was required for that particular layout.

Other layouts work fine in the layout-large qualifier.

The whole code is beneath : 
I gave the whole code because I have no idea which part is causing the problem.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="#B35555" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

                android:background="#eeeeee"

    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:background="#00B16A"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/form"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:text="@string/form"
                        android:textColor="#ffffff"
                        android:textColorHint="#ffffff"
                        android:textSize="17sp" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/button1"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:background="@drawable/home" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/layout_chap"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                     android:layout_margin="15dp"
                     android:layout_below="@+id/chap_heading"
                     android:background="@drawable/rounded">

                   <ScrollView
         android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:layout_marginLeft="5dp" >

         <LinearLayout
             android:id="@+id/chaps"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent"
             android:orientation="vertical" >


                 </LinearLayout>
                 </ScrollView>

                </RelativeLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/layout_others"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                    android:layout_margin="20dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/rounded"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/others">

                    <ScrollView
         android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:layout_marginLeft="5dp" >

         <LinearLayout
             android:id="@+id/others_layout"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent"
             android:orientation="vertical"

            >



                 </LinearLayout>
                 </ScrollView>

                </LinearLayout>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/chap_heading"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/layout_chap"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:text=" Chapterwise Formulae" 
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                    />
        <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/others"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/layout_others"


                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                     android:layout_below="@+id/layout_chap"
                     android:text="@string/others_text" />                  >

            </RelativeLayout>
        </ScrollView>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:background="#00B16A"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/phyid"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_vertical"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/chemid"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/button_form_phy"
        android:textColor="#ffffff" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/chemid"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/button_form_chem"
        android:textColor="#ffffff" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/mathid"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/chemid"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/button_form_math"
        android:textColor="#ffffff" />
</LinearLayout>
```

The last linear layout here contains buttons which are 9patch images. I read somewhere that it can cause such errors. Dont know why.

Comment: is it after you run in avd?

Comment: No, it happens in Eclipse preview screens. And its mostly Nexus phones that show this error.

Comment: can u please send your code